# How to disconnect a signal of Gtk?

Tags: gtk, signals

Will signals automatically disconnect, when target object is destroyed? Without recording the signal id from `g_signal_connect()`, can I remove that signal?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you didn't save the signal handler ID, you can search for it using [`g_signal_handler_find()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.signal_handler_find.html) and disconnect it the usual way, or disconnect any signals that match certain criteria with [`g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.signal_handlers_disconnect_matched.html) or [`g_signal_handlers_disconnect_by_func()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.signal_handlers_disconnect_by_func.html).

Answer (score 10):

Of course when the target object is destroyed, the signals connected to it are removed (otherwise there would be a massive memory leak, but read the warning on [g_signal_connect_object](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.signal_connect_object.html)). However, to call [g_signal_handler_disconnect](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.signal_handler_disconnect.html) you need the handler id given by `g_signal_connect` and friends.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *handler_block_by_func* and *handler_unblock_by_func* methods.

Example (PyGTK):

```
def on_treeview_fixedexpenses_cursor_changed(self, widget):
    self.checkbutton_fixedexpensetax.handler_block_by_func(self.on_checkbutton_fixedexpensetax_toggled)
    self.updateCurrentFixedExpense()
    self.checkbutton_fixedexpensetax.handler_unblock_by_func(self.on_checkbutton_fixedexpensetax_toggled)
```

Source: http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/class-gobject.html

Comment: It is unclear for me what your code does and how does it answer the question. Can you explain it a bit more please.